# JDO in google app engine other PrimaryKey than type "Key" key possible?

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

why isn't it possible to define another key than
      @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        private Key key;
?
If i try to define a @PrimaryKey as say, an Integer I get an Server Error...
 http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/dataclasses.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a Long

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

or a String

@PrimaryKey
private String name;

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html

Comment: public class Commit {
 @PrimaryKey
 private String ip;
}
does not work

Comment: Did you put @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION) before the class. Otherwise you'll have to tell me exactly what error you're getting

Comment: no. eclipse marks "APPLICATION" as error ( although it is in the api ... :/ )